# Sort Dataframe by two columns - so that the order of both columns doesnt matter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a Dataframe that looks like following:

| UID | Count1 | Count2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XXX | 1 | 1 |
| Xyy | 1 | 0 |
| yyy | 0 | 2 |

I want to sort that Dataframe based on the two Count-Columns. The order of the columns should not matter, plus equally distributed values should be on top.

It should look like this:

| UID | Count1 | Count2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XXy | 1 | 1 |
| yyy | 0 | 2 |
| Xyy | 1 | 0 |

Is there a way to achieve this with Pandas?

Comment: Can you explain your desired sorting order a bit more? ascending/descending?

Comment: I want it descending.

so a entry with Count1 = 2 and Count 2 = 2 should be higher than one with C1 =1 and C2 = 2.

C1 = 3 & C2 = 1 should be below C1 =2 & C2=2, because the values are not as equally distributed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort using standard deviation and sum, putting the highest sum and the lowest standard deviation at the top

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.array([[1,0,1,2],[1,2,0,0]])    
        
df = pd.DataFrame(arr).T
df.columns = (["Count1","Count2"])

#Get sum of columns
df['sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)
#Get standard deviation of columns
df['sd'] = df.std(axis=1)

#Sort by SD ascending and SUM descending
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['sd'], ascending=True).sort_values(by=['sum'], ascending=False)

#df_sorted
#Out[87]: 
#  Count1  Count2  sum        sd
#0       1       1    2  0.577350
#1       0       2    2  1.154701
#3       2       0    2  1.154701
#2       1       0    1  0.577350

#Take the first two columns
df = df_sorted[['Count1', 'Count2']]
```